# How to add website and address with google places api?

Tags: php, json, google-places-api, google-places

i am writing an application that will allow businesses to do SEO and i am using the google places api to add new place when the client has activated their profile.

The api works great, but i am limited for adding only a few arguments. I would like to know if there is a feature to add their website, working hours, phone and etc.

Also i would like to know after how long are those places going to be publicly visible on google maps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: point me to the docs where you can't find how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: i see here: [link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions#PlaceReportRequests)[/link] how to add a place and delete it, add name, location, but not website and address

Answer (score 0):

Only requests submitted from a small number of trusted applications are being moderated for integration into Google Places. If you wish to add a new place that can be accessed outside of your application you can follow the Google Maps help instructions to [Add a new place](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144367&topic=1687361&ctx=topic).

If you are a business owner, you can add and verify your business on Google Maps using [Google Places for Business](http://www.google.com/placesforbusiness).

Another alternative to add places to Google Maps is to submit an edit through [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker) by following the [instructions](http://support.google.com/mapmaker/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1096044&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=1wf9zf83h3bs7&cbrank=2) from Google Map Maker Help.

Your added place will appear in Google Maps after it has been reviewed and accepted.